# Cloudformation stack is not updating from service catalog

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-service-catalog

I am updating provisioned service catalog product from lambda function. it is working fine for many products but for one provisioned product when i try to update provisioned service catalog product it is successfully updating but cloud formation stack is not getting updated by service catalog

Here code of lambda function

import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):

```
client=boto3.client('servicecatalog')
response = client.update_provisioned_product(
AcceptLanguage='en',
ProvisionedProductId='pp-3mio2kzru2yc2',
ProductId='prod-zpvv57zereqfu',
ProvisioningArtifactId='pa-k3cx2pkgge4ce',
ProvisioningParameters=[
    {
        'Key': 'ScheduledScalingInDesiredInstances',
        'Value': '0',
        'UsePreviousValue': False
    },
     {
        'Key': 'ScheduledScalingInMaxInstances',
        'Value': '0',
        'UsePreviousValue': False
    },
     {
        'Key': 'ScheduledScalingInMinInstances',
        'Value': '0',
        'UsePreviousValue': False
    },
     {
        'Key': 'ScheduledScalingInCron',
        'Value': 'cron(42 19 * * ? *)',
        'UsePreviousValue': False
    },
    {
        'Key': 'EnvironmentName',
        'UsePreviousValue': True
    },
    {
        'Key': 'ClusterName',
        'UsePreviousValue': True
    },
    
]
```

)

[image]

Lambda function has required permissions as same role is used in another lambda function which is able to update cloudformation stack via provisioned service catalog.

what could be the reason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved.

Issue was with parameter mismatch. I was trying to update few parameters while dependent param should be updated as well